# Xcode Swift SpriteKit Background Color (behind Scene)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, skspritenode

I'm working with a GameViewController and the GameScene. This one is linked to a GameScene.sks. In the GameViewController I set the aspect radio to .aspectFit. So on the top and the bottom are black bars.
My Question is, how can I change the colors of this black bars?

The Things I tried (didn't work):

Creating a new SKNode with `background.size = self.frame.size`

In the GameView-Controller:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .white
scene.backgroundColor = .white
view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Comment: It would be soooo awesome, if someone can help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

self.backgroundColor = .white

Answer (score 0):

Dont' use **.aspectFit** instead use **.aspectFill**. Then, scale SKScene.size for actual screen.

You can reuse this method on re-scale methods like **viewWillTransitionToSize**, for iPad split screen for example.